# Publishing DotNetNuke (DNN) website to Azure virtual machine

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, dotnetnuke, azure-sql-database, dotnetnuke-6

I find my self in a bind here and I was hoping someone might have some tips to help.

I was sent a DNN website to put in my Azure virtual machine to host.  I am not very familiar with DNN, however I didn't think it would be too difficult.  Sadly, I was wrong.

I move the DNN databse to an Azure SQL database.  I copied everything from the DNN's "httpdocs" folder to my website's root folder on my VM.  I edited the web config to point the database connection strings to the new Azure SQL database.  I also had to grant the IIS user account writer permissions on the /app_data/ClientDependency folder based on an error I got when I first tried to run the website.  I thought this would be all I have to do, however when I browse to the website I get a 404 page.

Do I need to install some DNN software to get this working?  I tried to downing DNN on my VM via Web Platform installer (WPI).  In the WPI options I told it to use a remote database, however it keeps asking me for the "sa" database account's password to proceed.  Azure SQL doesn't let you use the "sa" account and I can't tell the WPI to use a different database account username.  I don't even think I need to install any DNN software as long as I uploaded all of the httpdocs files to my VM's website root, however I'm grabbing straws here.

Can anyone please provide any advice on how to get this working?  I've been googling for a long time and I haven't came up with anything :(

Thank you everyone.

Comment: Have a look here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16815066/migrate-an-existing-dotnetnuke-portal-to-windows-azure

Answer (score 1):

The 404 error is probably caused because your site has disabled the setting "Admin > Site Settings > Site Aliases > Auto Add Site Alias". After moving your site to Azure (or another location that uses a different URL), if that setting is disabled you need to manually add it on the database.

- **Add a new record in the PortalAlias** table specifying the Virtual Machine cloud service name (i.e. mywebsite.cloudapp.net)
- **Touch the web.config** file to ensure that the application pool is restarted and the cache cleared, so the portal alias table will be populated again from the database to memory.

Hope this helps.

Comment: The response header will show a 'portal alias not found' type message if it's a lack of portal alias (for DNN 7.2 and later, that is)